# Share React Native build

Tags: react-native

What options are available for sharing a react native build privately?

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to share the source code or share the build of the app?

Comment: I would like to share the build

Comment: You could use iTunes testflight if you have developer account for iOS. For android you could just bundle the app as apk and send to your friends.

Comment: @Hariks thanks for the solution. I've updated the question to simply ask what options are available for sharing the app build. From your comment I'm guess 3 options are iTunes testflight, send apk for Android, and possibly Expo for both?

Answer (score 0):

You could just push the build's code to a remote repo and make sure the compiled folders aren't ignored (can't recall if it's ignored by default or not, check your .gitignore file if using GitHub). I think private repo's are only part of GitHub premium, but if you share the code anywhere then someone would be able to open it in Xcode/Android Studio and then use those SDK's to run on a simulator or device.

Comment: I do have access to private Github repo's so that wouldn't be a problem. My issue would be that the people I want to share it with won't have Xcode/Android Studio installed so I won't be able to rely on that. Overall though, it seems like the 4 options are iTunes testflight, apk for Android, Github private repo with local SDK's and Expo. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a free account on bitbucket and pushing your code there.

The site is free (up to 5 users) and allows you to privately host your project

Comment: This solution does not share the build though, only the source code. The people I want to share it with won't have Xcode/Android Studio installed so I won't be able to rely on that.

Comment: I cant edit my comment above. Use test flight to have people look at your app. You have to be an apple developer though